# Copy specific files from specific folders (folders in .rar)

Tags: powershell

My folder structure looks like this:

```
SourceFolder
├─file1.txt
├─file1.doc
└─Subfolder1
  ├─file2.txt
  ├─file2.doc
  └─SubSubFolder
    ├─file3.txt
    └─doc3.txt
```

This script copies all *.txt files from folders, whose (folder) names contains the eng, to a destination folder. Only the files inside the folder.

```bsh
$dest = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Final"
$source = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test1"

Get-ChildItem $source -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -match "eng" } |
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_.fullname $dest }
```

In my situation the folders are in .rar format and I want the script to search .rar folders and copy the *.txt files from folder eng to destination. Is that possible with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

[Rar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_%28file_format%29) is a proprietary archive format. Your .rar items aren't folders but compressed archives of that format. PowerShell can't transparently handle such archives, and I'm not aware of a third-party provider that would add this functionality.

Basically, no, what you're asking isn't possible.

What you can do is extract files from the archive with tools like [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/), e.g.:

```
7z.exe e your.rar *.txt -r
```

For extracting only files from a nested subfolder inside the archive prepend the extract pattern with that path:

```
7z.exe e your.rar "nested\subfolder\*.txt" -r
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers for reply.  It's cumbersome to extract rar, Example on their website states 7z x archive.zip -oc:\soft *.cpp -r Explained extracts all *.cpp files from the archive archive.zip to c:\soft folder. Fine but mine is only folder eng folder exclude all others and extract only their txt files. Any alternate.